# VBA event functions Worksheet and Workbook_sheet

Tags: vba, excel, events

What is the difference between functions:
`Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`
`Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick`
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` is specific to whichever sheet the code is located in, whereas `Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick` will be triggered by double-clicking any sheet in the workbook (assuming you have it correctly located in the ThisWorkbook module).

Answer (score 2):

The Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick is a workbook level event and so the code in here would trigger for every sheet in the workbook if you double click
The Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick is a worksheet level event and so goes inside the individual worksheet and only applies to double clicking in that worksheet

Comment: If you are happy with this answer, could I be cheeky and ask that you mark it as "answered" As a site newbie, I need over 50 rep before I can add comments instead of having to write an "answer" post every time :-)